# Badge apparently awarded, but not showing

Tags: support, badges

On the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) StackExchange site on [my profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/364819/toroidal) in the Badge tracker it says that I have just been given a new Gold badge (I don't have any other gold badges so far):

[image: Copy Editor Badge]

But when looking in my badge stats:

[image: My Badge Stats]

And my list of currently awarded badges:

[image: List of currently awarded badges]

I see no evidence of this badge, so why is this? Is the process just slow, or is this some sort of bug? Because I just got awarded another badge and that appeared immediately, but I have been waiting at least 10 minutes for this one, and still nothing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The badge progress tracker is live - meaning that as long as the data is available to look at it will show you up-to-the-minute stats about how far along you are towards that badge.

The scripts that *award* those badges are on timed cycles, ranging from every few minutes to once a day. It will take some time between the profile page saying "yay, you've made it to the end" and the system actually giving out the badge.

It looks like the system process has already run and awarded you the badge now.

Comment: Yes, it appears to have awarded the badge now, so obviously was just taking a long time.